# How do I implement one to many relationship in django?

Tags: python, django

So I have a case where I have to use one to many relationship in django, I don't know how to use it. I want to implement one to many relationship in `order(one)`  `to product(s)` which could be many. My code is like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: check the documentation about relationships https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/

Comment: What you speak of is clearly a ManyToMany relationship between order and product, not a one to many. Otherwise one product can only be present in one order which is likely not what you want. Use a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you have M:N relation between `User` and `Product`, because one `Product` can be member of multiple `Order`s, and `Order` can contain multiple `Products`. It's modeled as two 1:N relations as visualized below.

```
    ┌─────────┐
    │ Product │
    │ - name  │◄──┐
    │ - price │   │        ┌───────────────┐
    └─────────┘   └────────┤ Order         │
                           │- <FK> User    │
    ┌─────────┐   ┌────────┤- <FK> Product │
    │ User    │   │        └───────────────┘
    │ - name  │◄──┘
    └─────────┘
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Comment: How can I add multiple products using that in code? Also thanks for your answer